# How to verify JSON output with RestFixture using googleapis

Tags: json, google-api

See below my code, it is not executing. What am I missing here?

```
start slim
!path C:\Fitnesse\RestFixture\lib\*.jar
!path C:\Fitnesse\RestFixture\lib\smartrics-RestFixture-3.0.jar
!define expectedReturnHeaders {Content-Length : [\d]+   
Content-Type : application/json }
|!-Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture-! |        https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0735619670|
|GET| Content-Type : application/json |jsonbody.items[0].id=="QnghAQAAIAAJ"
```

I am getting error as

```
jsonbody.items.id=="QnghAQAAIAAJ"

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot evaluate 'jsonbody.items.id=="QnghAQAAIAAJ"' in {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: q",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: q"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample code

```
|!-    Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture-!|http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json|
|setHeader              |!-Accept: application/json-!                    |
|GET                    |?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway   |200   |      |!-/* javascript */
result = false;
var addr = jsonbody.results[0].address_components;
for (i in addr) {
   if (addr[i].types[0]==='route') {
     if (addr[i].long_name==='Amphitheatre Parkway') {
        result = true;
    }
 }
}
result;
 -!|
```